# How to make my ANTD style fall within that scope only

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, antd

I created a project using react typescript with ANTD. The folder structure I use is where each page has its own folder, which contains `file.tsx` and `file.css.`

In this case I am creating a Login Folder which contains `Login.tsx` and `Login.css`. In the Login file I customize some `antd` styles. But the style is out of scope of the Login. What I can think of is to use the CSS module but that's just styles for CSS not for ANTD. Is there a way I can make my ANTD style only exist in the Login scope only?

EDITED:
This is mycode css code for customize antd:

```
/* custom ant design style */

.ant-input{
    width: 280px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
}

.ant-btn {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    margin: 40px 0 !important;
    background-color: #149BD4 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

/* customize button when hover focus and active */
.ant-btn:hover, .ant-btn:focus, .ant-btn:active{
    background-color: #149BD4 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

/* customize position of label */
.ant-form-vertical .ant-form-item-label, .ant-col-24.ant-form-item-label, .ant-col-xl-24.ant-form-item-label {
    text-align: center !important;
}

.ant-form-vertical .ant-form-item-label > label {
    color: #149BD4 !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
```

And it is my `Login.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Stetoscope } from '../../assets/Stetoscope'
import { Button, Form, Row } from 'antd'
import './index.css'
import './login.css'
import Input from '../form/Input'
import InputPassword from '../form/InputPassword'
export const DataLogin: React.FC = () => {
    const onFinish = (val: any) => {

    }
    return (
        <div className="layout">
            <div className="layout__left">
                <Stetoscope />
            </div>
            <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish} className="layout__right">
                <div className="layout__right__container">
                    <div className="layout__right__container__body">
                        <h1>Sign In</h1>
                        <Row>
                            <Input className="auth-input" name="username" label="Username" />
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <InputPassword className="auth-input" name="password" label="Password" />
                        </Row>
                        <Button>Log in</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And that script showing in `Login.tsx`:

[image]

And in another page outside Login scope it is showing:
[image]

Comment: Please share your code illustrating your problem.

Comment: I have added the code. Is there a solution so that the `antdesign` style doesn't go out of the login scope, sir?

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` in the css files. I think that's enough to solve your problem.